Splintered and visible porch support - what to do?
A contractor added a porch and one of the beams that goes to the roof is splintered.  They declared it done but after complaining they did a bad job boxing it in,
They want the last third of their money less $2,000 K that can be withheld.  The total job was 50K.
Will there be any issues with the splintered support down the road?  Should I pay the bill less 2K?



I was thinking you may be a little too "fussy" about the look of framing lumber, however that giant split is ridiculous.  It could be lethal to someone.  Is the second pic the result after they boxed it in?   If so, that is not bad at all.

Is that a 6x6 post? Is it just holding up a roof?

Yes, this is holding up a roof.

If it’s a 6x6 post, there’s plenty of strength there and you can’t see it anymore, so I’d call it complete and that the invoice is due in full.

Prices off topic, Legal questions off topic.
Ah, excessively rustic!  I'm guessing someone at the lumber yard hit it with the forklift.
Trying to cover it up will be tricky especially if the cover is not fully weatherproof, hence the cracks.
I suggest saw or plane it to dimension (plane off the bits that stick out) . then fill the gap with tinted bondo.

Great comment about potential issues with coveringi t up.  Bondo is an interesting idea.  From this Forum and other I get this is not a major structural issue.

Yes, not major, you can notch a post 1/4 way through and not worry about it.
